# Outlook delegate calendaring feature

Tags: microsoft-outlook

There used to be a feature in either Outlook 2003/2007 that was extremely helpful as a calendar delegate for multiple managers that when I sorted my email inbox by type and highlighted the meeting requests section and pressed delete on the keyboard, all of the meetings that were already responded to were deleted leaving only the invites that were awaiting a response.  This is especially helpful as the  managers are outside of the US and sometimes respond to their own requests, however, it is tedious for me to have to go through each invite to see if there was a response already.  Is there a way to either bring that feature back or maybe create a rule in Outlook 2010?

Answer (score 1):

In Outlook 2010 and upwards this is something Outlook does automatically. You can however change these settings by doing the following.

Click on File
Click on Options
Click on Mail
Scroll to Send Messages Option
Check/Uncheck the box next to delete meeting requests after response(I believe it's something like that)

Comment: Thank you!  I was looking more specifically how to have them removed when it is another calendar that I am a delegate for.  I apologize for not being specific in my original question and therefore have re-worded to add clarity.

Comment: Are those managers also using Outlook 2010 and above? Is there a common subject line for the meetings which have been accepted/declined? Because in Outlook 2010 if the manager has not responded and you try to delete the invite, it will remove the invite from their calendar as well.